# Can I use an unlocked T-Mobile Galaxy S5 on AT&T?

Tags: att, gsm, t-mobile, 4g, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I made the unfortunate mistake of buying a Galaxy S5 through AT&T and was rewarded with a locked bootloader and no fun whatsoever for any reason ever.

As a remedy, I've considered purchasing a T-Mobile Galaxy S5 and somehow unlocking  it (how does that process work again?) for use on AT&T.

Two questions:

1. Will it be compatible with most (if not all) bands on AT&T? (ie: will I lack anything or will I be able to use the network just as well as with the AT&T S5?)
2. How do I unlock a device for use on a different carrier?

According to [AT&T](https://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/samsung/galaxy-s-5-charcoal-black.html#fbid=fUFfWuDxx3s), these are the supported bands for the AT&T S5:

1. 4G-LTE: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, and 17
2. 4G: HSPA+ with enhanced backhaul
3. 3G - UTMS: 840, 1900, 2100MHz
4. GSM/GPRS/EDGE: 850, 900, 1800, 1900MHz

According to [T-Mobile](http://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phones/samsung-galaxy-s-5.html?icid=WMM_TM_SMSNGGLXYS_04BTTJZOAN144#features), these are the supported bands for the T-Mobile S5:

1. LTE: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, and 17
2. UMTS: Band 1 (2100), Band 2 (1900), Band 4 (1700/2100), Band 5 (850)
3. "Quad Band GSM" (what bands?)

It seems to be compatible.

<sup>See also [AT&T Radio Frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T_Mobility#Radio_frequency_summary) and [T-Mobile Radio Frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-Mobile_USA#Radio_frequency_spectrum_chart)</sup>

**Will it work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. T-mobile S5 is my daily driver. I have a T-mo SIM card in it, but every time I go on a road trip up north T-mo contracts their service out to AT&T and my S5 connects to AT&T's towers, telling me so in the notification pulldown bar and the lockscreen.

Comment: I've been using mine on AT&T for a year now.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's what I can gather...

1. There should be no real loss of capability if you move to AT&T. While AT&T does not advertise LTE Band 8 capability on its S5s, Band 8 is largely used in South Korea, Japan, and Taiwan; unless you travel to those places, it shouldn't be a problem. I would, however, check AT&T's [coverage map](http://www.att.com/maps/wireless-coverage.html) to be certain.
2. T-Mobile allows customers to unlock phones provided certain conditions are met. Click [here](http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-1588) for more information.

Also, "Quad Band GSM" on T-Mobile is 850/900/1800/1900 MHz, same as AT&T